# Open source cross platform IDE for python3 with debugger and code completion

Tags: python, linux, ide, python-3.x, editor

What are good cross platform python3 IDEs with debugger and code completion? I found some, but none of them had the 4 features at once: support for python3 syntax, code completion, integrated debugger and being free. The only one that has them is python plugin for eclipse, but unfortunatelly eclipse is so slow on my pc (you know: *knock knock* "who's there?" *3 secs of silence* "java"), so I want something different. But I just cant find anything that is free and works on linux easily. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of question does not fit the format of this site, see the [FAQ#dontask]. Questions like these tend to lead to vague answers that are also outdated very quickly. If we can help you with a specific problem, feel free to post another question though!

Comment: Even if I'm asking for listing a few IDEs and not asking which one is best? Well here are lib questions also and many of them are outdated too (like wx vs qt), but for the time of writing a question the answers were valid. Well but if I can't ask, I will ask in other place ;)

Comment: There is an extensive list of all the python ides [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python).

Comment: WingIDE, although not all editions are free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eric5](https://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) is a full featured Python and Ruby editor and IDE, written in python. It is based on the cross platform Qt gui toolkit, integrating the highly flexible Scintilla editor control. It is designed to be usable as everdays' quick and dirty editor as well as being usable as a professional project management tool integrating many advanced features Python offers the professional coder. eric4 includes a plugin system, which allows easy extension of the IDE functionality with plugins downloadable from the net.

A couple of others...

[Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/)

[PyScripter](https://github.com/pyscripter/pyscripter)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/). If you have a browser, you can use it.